# Python calling a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do one of the exercises from learn python the hard way and am stuck on something. I created a function and in case one of the statements is fulfilled I would like to put that in another function. This is the outline of how I'm trying to do it:

```
def room_1():
    print "Room 1"
    button_push = False

    while True:
       next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "1":
            print "You hear a click but nothing seems to happen."
            button_push = True

        elif next == "2":
            print "You enter room 2"
            room_2()

def room_2():
    print "Room 2"

    while True:
        next =raw_input("> ")

        if next == "1" and button_push:
            print "You can enter Room 3"
            room_3()
```

If button_push is fulfilled then I would like to see that in room_2. Could anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `button_push` as an argument to the next room:

```
def room_1():
    print "Room 1"
    button_push = False

    while True:
       next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "1":
            print "You hear a click but nothing seems to happen."
            button_push = True

        elif next == "2":
            print "You enter room 2"
            room_2(button_push)  # pass button_push as argument

def room_2(button_push):  # Accept button_push as argument
    print "Room 2"

    while True:
        next =raw_input("> ")

        if next == "1" and button_push:  # button_push is now visible from this scope
            print "You can enter Room 3"
            room_3()
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! Is there a way to pass button_push only if I input "1" first and "2" only after?

Comment: @user2714517 You're passing `True` if they inputted `1` and then `2` or `False` otherwise. If you need to know whether `1` then `2` was pressed, you can just check for the value of `button_push`. Since you have `and button_push`, you'll only enter room 3 if they inputted `1` then `2`.